# Удаление SKShapeNode

Tags: spritekit, xcode, objective-c, ios7

Я создал например спрайт:

SKShapeNode *sprite = [SKShapeNode node];

А как его удалить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это SpriteKit то

```
[sprite removeFromParent];
```